# form does not submit and refresh back to same page when return false is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

i have previously posted about triggering a dialog box before confirming a submit. But, unfortunately the document now does not submit. Instead, it stays on the same page with the exact same setting. I have tested, if i remove the return false over at submitform function, the document submit will go through but it would not be triggered by "proceed" button. So in this case, i believe the return false has to be around but how can i ensure my document will and only submit successfully after clicking "proceed"? I think this is purely a javascript problem because my back end works.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitform(){
        $("#dialog-submit").dialog("open");
        return false
    }

    $("#dialog-submit").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Proceed": function(){
                //submit.
        //tried document.submitform.submit();  does not work either         
                document.forms[0].submit();
                $(this).dialog("close");

            }
        }
    });
     </script>


 <form name="submitform" action="{{ request.path }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="image" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/submit.png" title="Submit Iteration" name="submitIter" onclick="return submitform();" value="{{ i.iter.key.id }}" width="25px"/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try writing your code as [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Here's an [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/EU6a3/) for a fix.

Comment: The jsfiddle works. Does your implementation of my code not work? What error are you getting? The point of the variable `fromDialog` is self explanatory!